# php pagination should start from 1 not 0

Tags: php, pagination

This is my function to download and paginate data from xml file.

```
<?php 
function get_feed_posts($link) {

        if(!isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $_GET['page'] = 0;
        }

        $startPage = $_GET['page'];
        $perPage = 13;
        $currentRecord = 0;
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($link, 0, true);

        foreach($xml->results->result as $item) {
            $currentRecord += 1;
            if($currentRecord > ($startPage * $perPage) && $currentRecord < ($startPage * $perPage + $perPage)) {
        ?>
            <li><a class="go-to" href="<?php echo $item->click_url;?>" title="<?php echo $item->name;?>">Go to store</a></li>

        <?php

            }

        }

        for ($i = 0; $i <= ($currentRecord / $perPage); $i++) {
            $n=$i+1;
            echo("<a href='?page=".$n."'>".$n."</a>");
        }

} ?>
```

This code works great. But I want to have my pages starting from `?page=1`, now this code starts from `?page=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
<?php 
function get_feed_posts($link) {

    if(!isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $_GET['page'] = 1; // changed this line
    }

    $startPage = ($_GET['page'] < 1) ? 0 : $_GET['page'] - 1;  // changed this line
    $perPage = 13;
    $currentRecord = 0;
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($link, 0, true);

    foreach($xml->results->result as $item) {
        $currentRecord += 1;
        if($currentRecord > ($startPage * $perPage) && $currentRecord < ($startPage * $perPage + $perPage)) {
    ?>
        <li><a class="go-to" href="<?php echo $item->click_url;?>" title="<?php echo $item->name;?>">Go to store</a></li>

    <?php

        }

    }

    for ($i = 0; $i <= ($currentRecord / $perPage); $i++) {
        $n=$i+1;
        echo("<a href='?page=".$n."'>".$n."</a>");
    }

} ?>
```

Notice that any `x` in `?page=x` smaller than 1 will be treated as 0, but you could do better (throw an error? redirect to `?page=1`?).

Comment: Try again, was just a typo